# Is it safe to browse inside from a virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

Is there any potential risk in doing any transaction or browsing some secure pages inside from a virtual box?

Comment: The risks are generally the same as if you were browsing from a physical machine.

Comment: Is your question, 'Is the host machine safe when browsing within a guest machine (VirtualBox)?'

Comment: Any potential risk, there is indeed a potential risk, if you want to be real secure use a physical machine that is rolled back to a specfic image after every reboot. This also means you have to update the system state when any new updates are released.  Any machine you think might get infected shouldn't be connected to your network.  You can give a VM internet and have it closed off from the network.

Answer (score 2):

To surf Internet or do risky or whatever actions will just be the same as you are in physical machine, **but** with respect to the VM itself. **But** if you are asking if this will affect your host machine then the answer will be NO. whatever you did inside your VM it will not affect your physical host.

Thanks to @kobaltz :

You can still be affected with Viruses that spread aacross networks will just as likely infect the host machine as well as other machines on the network depending on the vNIC settings.

Comment: Not true necessarily. Viruses that spread across networks will just as likely infect the host machine as well as other machines on the network depending on the vNIC settings.

Comment: yes sure but this is not related directly to the choose of VM or physical machine, it's related to network. but thanks for your note. I'lla dd it to the answer